# how to configure dual wlan at boot on rhel 6

Tags: wireless-networking, redhat-enterprise-linux, rhel-6

I got a RHEL 6.3 box, with 2 wlan interfaces.

I need wlan to be set at boot.

```
wlan0 -> connects to NETWORK0
wlan1 -> connects to NETWORK1
```

How should I setup this ?

I'm not used to ifcfg scripts.